# Ask for user confirmation then continue with the method mvc 5 c#

Tags: javascript, c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-5

in the code I have a method that reads data from an excel sheet and store the record in a list, I want to compare certain columns with the database records if they exist I want to ask the user (take the user conformation with "confirm" in javascript for example) if he wants to replace the new data with the old one or keep the old one, my issue is how can I go to the view to ask the user then go back to continue with my method? or if there is a way to ask the user without going to the view

my controller

```
 foreach (var n in KPlist)
                {

                    var compare = _db.Kpiprograms.Where(x => x.ProgramId == n.ProgramId && x.Year == n.Year && x.Term == n.Term && x.KpiId == n.KpiId).Any();
                    if (compare)
                    {
                      //am stuck here 
                    }
                 
                }
```

Comment: MVC is stateless. You can't jump back and forth between backend and UI as in a windows application. You need an entirely different approach. For example, store the excel data in a table and present the data side-by-side with db data in a UI where a user can select the records they want to be updated. I think this is even easier for users because they can review their decisions before saving.

Comment: You can use `AJAX` to call your method and get a response back and then process the data accordingly.